# How to make an Image Transparent to back ground

Tags: java, android

I have just created a simple row.xml for gridView like this [image]
but WHen I run the app It shows like this [image] All I need this back ground of an Image View would be transparent not have a grey back ground color
and this is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tabless"></ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datetv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="20:20pm"
            android:textSize="10dp">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tablesnumberstv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="5"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checknumbertv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="50"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversnumbertv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_image"
            android:text="5" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

sorry if any thing is unClear

Comment: do you have windowbackground in theme used for the activity?

Comment: in xml for background attribute set "#80000000"

Comment: shall I add this to the parent layout or just put it in the back ground of an ImageView @MCZ 57

Comment: I can't understand what you mean exactly @Raghunandan

Comment: what kind of image you have used in item_image png or jpeg

Comment: I used png type @Tapan Kumar Patro

Comment: Can we see the @drawable/tabless code?

Comment: @Dev.7arooney just put it in an image background tag

Comment: @Dev.7arooney  do you have any theme set for activity in Manifest.xml and do you set a windowbackground??

Comment: @Dev.7arooney please let me know if this is the issue with height and width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add a background:

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tabless"></ImageView>
```

Comment: It shows the same result as I post in a pic @MadScientist

Comment: wait let me check again

Comment: Ok tyt @MadScientist

Comment: Hey, try this code [here](http://pastebin.com/hjLm86am)

Comment: @Dev.7arooney did it work?

Comment: I have the same problem @MadScientist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138513/discussion-between-madscientist-and-dev-7arooney).

Answer (score 2):

Make the background of the ImageView transparent:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: It shows the same result as I post in a pic @Kai Ku

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="null"
```

> Make the background of the imageview as null or make it white it will match to the color of the LinearLayout background color.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys sorry I just have a silly mistake with this code

```
Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.table);
```

I replced it to

```
Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tabless);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
```

In this code you have given background #fff which is white color, If you have taken png format image then just remove background from relative layout .. It will work

Comment: problem is not with the white its with the grey

Comment: Then i think problem with this two line `android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"` he should have give height as wrap_content or fill_parent

Comment: yes possibly. that's the same i suggested him [here](http://pastebin.com/hjLm86am)

Comment: Thnks so much @MadScientist,